# ¿Por qué SOes y SOes Meta no tienen el mismo estilo?

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario

Stack Overflow español Meta:
[image: SOes Meta]
Stack Overflow espanol:
[image: SOes]

¿Por qué el formato/estilo que se le da a ambos sitios no es el mismo? ¿No debería serlo?

He visto que en otros sitios de Stack Exchange ocurre lo mismo. A mí en lo personal me gustaría que fueran más consistentes, en los colores por lo menos, y en este icono:  [image: Icono SOes]

Comment: son consistentes y tienen el mismo estilo. Cambia la paleta de colores por que es un **sitio separado con otro proposito** y los colores ayudan a comunicar en cual sitio estas (ademas de que cambia nombre, incluye -meta-)

Comment: Y, además de la paleta, recordemos que en Meta no hay reputación, y por eso las diferencias en la parte inferior de la captura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Porque son sitios distintos con distintos propósitos.**

En mi trabajo con frecuencia me conecto a múltiples ordenadores. De desarrollo, de integración, maquetas, en producción, servidores, etc.
Y para hacerlo uso un script que me lanza terminales con letras y fondos de distintos colores. Los de equipos de producción en rojo chillón (**CUIDADO CON LO QUE HACES, QUE ESTO ES SERIO**). Esto me ayuda a evitar errores que pueden suceder cuando tienes múltiples conexiones abiertas y puedes confundirte pensando que estás donde no estás.

En el estilo de SOes y SOes meta usan el mismo concepto.